# PHP curl_strerror or curl_error preference

Tags: php, curl, error-handling

I have a general PHP Curl-related question regarding the ways to get an error message when a curl error occurs.

- `curl_error` (returns a string containing last error for the current
  session) supported in (PHP 4 >= 4.0.3, PHP 5, PHP 7)
- `curl_strerror`
  (returns a string describing the given error code) supported in (PHP
  5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)

I did a search of PHP curl_strerror vs curl_error and didn't find much out there.

I have encountered a few servers in my chain that are running PHP 5.3 so using curl_strerror is not supported.
To prevent issues, I added some code ( version_compare ) to determine whether the server has at minimum PHP 5.5 but my curiosity is in the need to do that kind of check at all.

I suppose its a matter of preference of getting detailed string based on the curl error code via `curl_strerror` or using `curl_error`.

I'm interested in opinions. Which is the better approach?  Just take the info from curl_error (for PHP 4 or higher), or apply additional code (with a conditional) to go with curl_strerror when the PHP version is at least 5.5?

Comment: Since you asked for _opinions_: I wouldn’t bother, anyone who’s still using a PHP version < 5.5 has other problems. (Active support even for 5.5 ended 7 month ago, and security fixes will be provided for the next four month only.) Backwards compatibility is not even desirable in this case IMHO.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @CBroe. I decided to go with the code `curl_error` since it will work all of the time and not be dependent so much on PHP Version.

Sadly, after contacting Dev Ops, I learned we have some servers here that are running at 5.5 and some at 5.3 (so sad trombone), but we do what we must, with what we have.

Cheers